# Linq returns multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq

I made a linq for test, nothing special:

```
        public IEnumerable<Flight> GetActiveFlights(IEnumerable<Flight> flights)
    {
        return from flight in flights
            from segments in flight.Segments
            where segments.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now
            select new Flight
            {
                Segments = flight.Segments
            };
    }
```

And it returns multiple rows, each row for each segment in flight =/

Example:

Flight list has:
Segment 1, Segment2

Segment1 list has: departure, arrival
Segment2 list has: departure, arrival

Instead of:

> Departure: 2.9.2013 4:50:51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 7:50:51;
>
> Departure: 2.9.2013 5:50:51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 7:50:51; Departure: 2.9.2013 8:50 :51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 10:50:51;

I get:

> Departure: 2.9.2013 4:50:51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 6:50:51;
>
> Departure: 2.9.2013 5:50:51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 7:50:51; Departure: 2.9.2013 8:50 :51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 10:50:51;
>
> Departure: 2.9.2013 5:50:51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 7:50:51; Departure: 2.9.2013 8:50 :51, Arrival: 2.9.2013 10:50:51;

Which means, I get double records, if there is more than 1 segment in flight.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> And it returns multiple rows, each row for each segment in flight =/

Yes, that's because you've got a cross-join effectively, here:

```
from flight in flights
from segments in flight.Segments
```

I suspect you want something more like this:

```
from flight in flights
where flight.Segments.Any(seg => seg.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now)
select new Flight { Segments = flight.Segments };
```

Or if you only want to include the future segments:

```
from flight in flights
let futureSegments = flight.Segments
                           .Where(seg => seg.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now)
                           .ToList()
where futureSegments.Any()
select new Flight { Segments = futureSegments };
```

Note that the `ToList()` call makes sure that `flight.Segments` is only evaluated once per flight. The same could potentially be done for the first query, although it's less important there unless `flight.Segments` *really* can't be evaluated more than once.

As an aside, be very careful about using `DateTime.Now`, as that's always in local time - this is *particularly* relevant with flights which naturally cross time zone boundaries; I'd suggest keeping everything in UTC where possible.

Comment: both of these queries involve iterating `flights` n times, which might be a problem.  The last query also iterates `futureSegments` multiple times, which means doing the filtering multiple times.  Depending on the underlying implementation of `flights`, and the specific data you have, this could be just fine, but it could be either very performant, or possibly even not working.

Comment: Great explanation again. You really put effort for explaining for people to understand.

Btw about future segments, what does it mean? Like segment2, segment3, without segment1?

Comment: @JohnMathilda: It's sort of like a temporary variable - just the result of executing that query (the segments for that specific flight which have a future departure date).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's because you are iterating over the each child segment in the filter as well, which will cause a join, which is likely where the records are coming from.

The query you want is this I believe

```
return from flight in flights
       where flight.Segments.Any(x => x.DepartureDate > DateTime.Now)
       select flight;
```